# Detecting if a user clicked on Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

It looks like:

```
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
            alert("Hi");
        });
```

works for everybody except me!
Here is my code:

```
         <html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
                               .
                               .
                               .
         <body>
         <div id="section1">    
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
         <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
         <script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
               appId :'xxx',
               status : true, 
               cookie : true,
               xfbml : true, 
               oauth : true 
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
               alert("Hi");
            });
          });

          (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

          <fb:like href="mysite" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false" font="tahoma"></fb:like>


     </div>
```

I just need a simple way to check if the like button was clicked to show a form on the page! Any Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: take a look at this and check you code what you are missing. http://www.saschakimmel.com/2010/05/how-to-capture-clicks-on-the-facebook-like-button/. This works 10 out 10 for us... :)

Comment: Thanks Ram, it worked but the project is getting more complicated and 2 like buttons should be included in the page!!

Comment: you can even track multiple like buttons, check the code snippet below. It is the same event that gets triggered with different href or Like URL value.

Answer (score 3):

You can even detect multiple likes on the same page. We use this quite often, check the below snippet.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {

  // START: LOGIC For detecting multiple likes on the same page
   if(href == "LINK_1_ON_THEPAGE') {
       alert('User Like is for Link1');
   } else if (href == "LINK_2_ON_THEPAGE') {
       alert('User Like is for Link2');
   }
  // END: LOGIC For detecting multiple likes on the same page

 });
};
```

Comment: Works great. As far as I tested it, you can also omit the `FB.init(..)` line.